# Regexp: replacing all [[??]] with {{param|??}}

Tags: regex

I'm hoping some regexp guru to help me out with this:

I have strings such as `[[AB]]`, `[[ABC]]` and `[[BEC]]`, and I want to replace them with string `{{param|AB}}`, `{{param|ABC}}` and `{{param|BEC}}` respectively.

All source strings are inside [[]] and have 2 or 3 upper case letters. The idea is to transfer the letters inside brackets to the new format. It's fine if I need two different regexps for 2 and 3 letter long cases.

(if curious, this is for replacing large number of links with templates in a Mediawiki based page).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: What is the tool/language?

Comment: Tool is Mediawiki search & replace extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the result of following regex :

```
/\[\[([A-Z]{2,3})\]\]/
```

with :

```
{{/param\|\1/}}
```

Not that some regex engines use `$` for capture group so you may need to use `{{/param\|$1/}}`

If you want to exclude some words you can use a negative look ahead :

```
/^\[\[((?!AAA|BBB|CCC)[A-Z]{2,3})]]$/gm
```

But note that since that preceding regex use anchors if you are dealing with a multiline string you need to use `m` flag (multiline flag).

See demo https://regex101.com/r/cR8zG6/1

Comment: Escaping of the ending square brackets may not be required. `\[\[[A-Z]{2,3}]]`

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Indeed, ;-).

Comment: This worked! However, I found out there are certain 3 letter matches that would need to be excluded. Is it possible to exclude certain strings from match? I.e. match all 2-3 letter strings except AAA, BBB and CCC (or any other combo)? 

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can search using this regex:

```
\[\[(\w+)\]\]
```

and replace using:

```
{{param|$1}}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dP0bD3/6)

Comment: /\[\[([A-Z]{2,3})\]\]/ was better, as \w+ matches any string inside brackets, not just the wanted kind. Thanks anyways!

Comment: `\w` matches only word characters which means digits, letters and `_`